# No Bean Found in Spring Boot application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Component
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("promotion")
public class PromotionConfig {
    private AppClientConfig appConfig;
}


@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AppClientConfig {
   private int readTImeout;
   private int writeTimeout;
}
```

When I am trying to do @Autowire PromotionConfig It is throwing an error that No Qualifying bean found for AppClientConfig.

I know this error is coming up because I dont have @Component in AppClientConfig.

How can i make it work without adding @Component in AppClientConfig. I want to keep it Plain POJO class.

My local.yml file

```
promotion:
  appConfig:
    readTImeout: 10
    writeTimeout: 10
```

Comment: You can create your instance of AppClientConfig and supply to the spring container

Comment: I don't see why there should be any. You should be injecting the `PromotionConfig` which contains the `appConfig` you need. The `AppClientConfig` shouldn't be a component,. If it is even detected it would have no values (well all 0) because the properties wouldn't bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load statically the spring bean in non spring classes as:

```
PromotionConfig PromotionConfig = ApplicationInitializer.getAppContext().getBean(PromotionConfig.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Spring you have another way to do so: using `Bean` configuration:

```
@Bean
public AppClientConfig configureAppClientConfig(){
   return new AppClientConfig(); // You can use your own way to create the instance
}
```

**Note:** the above bean configuration should be implemented in a Spring configuration class.

And finally, you need to call using `@Autowired`:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Component
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("promotion")
public class PromotionConfig {
    @Autowired
    private AppClientConfig appConfig;
}
```

Comment: It is taking value from .yaml file.

Comment: You have issues reading from yaml file? or your problem is just how to instantiate AppClientConfig?

Comment: Ideally it automatically reads from yaml becaue configuration properties is added

Comment: But since AppConfig is not @Component then it is not taking it

Comment: In the bean configuration instead of creating the instance directly using the default constructor, you can fill the inputs from yaml file.